# linked list debugging (delete C++ keyword is mysterious)?

Tags: c++, list

I am trying to solve a problem: Delete a node from a singly linked list give only a pointer to that node. My approach is to overwrite the data of the next element in the list onto the current element of the list.

In the code below, I have two versions of the deleting code: deleteNode and deleteNode2.

```
void deleteNode(Node * x) {

while(x->next != NULL){
    x->data = x->next->data;
    x = x->next;
}

delete x;
x=NULL;

}

void deleteNode2(Node * x) {

while(x->next->next != NULL){
     x->data = x->next->data;
    x = x->next;
 }

 x->data = x->next->data;
delete x->next;
x->next=NULL;

}
```

I initialized the list with: 1,2,3,4,5 and tried to delete node 3. For deleteNode the output is: 1,2,4,5,0 while for deleteNode2: 1,2,4,5

Also when I remove the "x->next=NULL" line from deleteNode2 it has the same output with 1. My question is, how does the delete statement work in C++? Does it set all bits in the pointed to by the address to 0?

For deleteNode(..), the x pointer has been deleted but it is not appropriately been set to NULL because it prints 0 instead of skipping it. For deleteNode2, the statement "x->next=NULL" is equivalent to "x=NULL" in deleteNode since both pointers conceptually point to the same address, but they don't have the same effect?

The rest of the code is shown below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
 int data;
Node * next;

Node ( int a ) { 
   data = a ; 
      next = NULL; 
    }

};

bool appendToTail ( Node * ptr, int a ){

  while (ptr->next != NULL)
  ptr = ptr->next;

  if (ptr==NULL) {
      return false; 
  }
 else {
    ptr->next = new Node(a);
 }

}

void printList (Node * head) {

 while (head!=NULL){

     cout<<head->data<<endl;
     head = head->next;

}

}

int main(void) {

Node * head;
head = new Node(1);
appendToTail(head,2);
 appendToTail(head,3);
appendToTail(head,4);
appendToTail(head,5);

Node * i = head->next->next;

printList(head);
cout<<"removed:"<<endl;

deleteNode2(i);

printList(head);    

return 0;

}
```

Comment: When you post or edit a question, there is an orange ? to the right. Click if for help on formatting. Use 4 spaces and don't use tabs to get the correct indent level.

Comment: Not what you asked about, but your `deleteNode()` implementation seems very broken to me. You don't need a loop, and you need to set the *previous* node's `next` pointer to the to-be-deleted node's `next` pointer. And because of the loop, you're actually deleting the pointer to the last node, not the intended node.

Comment: @dvnrrs That's the catch. It is singly linked list. So you don't have access to the previous node. That would have been easy. Yes, in effect I am deleting the pointer to the last node.

Comment: Without a pointer to a previous node, it's impossible to remove only  one node and keep the rest of the list intact, unless the node being deleted is assumed to be the head of the list. Go back and reread your assignment more carefully; you've probably misunderstood the intent.

Comment: @RobKennedy You can. It's a "simulated" delete because you will be overwriting the data part. Conceptually, you are shifting all the elements to the left/right. So the objects are not stored on their original addresses but the new list looks like the node was deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer as to why x doesn't change can be demonstrated with a simpler program:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int x)
{
   x = 10;  // change it to 10
}

int main()
{
   int num = 4;
   foo(num);
   std::cout << num; // num is still 4!  Why?
}
```

So why is num still 4?  Why didn't the value change to 10?  Look up "pass-by-value", because that is what you're doing in your pointer code.

You should be either passing the pointer by reference, or a pointer to the pointer (if you need further explanation, fix the example above to make num equal to 10 on return to foo).

Comment: I believe your answer is incorrect. If I use your argument about "pass-by-value" then why did it work for x->next=NULL in deleteNode2? Also, I am passing a copy of the pointer, deleting the object pointed by the pointer should have the same effect as using the original pointer.  example:  Pointer A points to objectX. Pointer B is a copy of A. If I do "delete B;" it should also delete objectX. Am I right?

Comment: @dean the answer *is* correct. `x` itself is a variable which holds a pointer. The *variable* was passed-by-value, so setting the variable to `NULL` has no effect outside the function. But if you modify the contents of the memory it points to, those changes *are* visible outside the function. The memory wasn't passed by value, the pointer to it was.

Comment: @dvnrrs Okay. I understand that part now. Since the x->next is actually the pointer inside the Node object so it works in that case. But with x=NULL it doesn't because x is only visible in that function. However, isn't the statement "delete x;" should take care of the whole deletion? According to C++ reference: delete "Deallocates the memory block pointed by ptr (if not null), releasing the storage space previously allocated to it by a call to operator new[] and rendering that pointer location invalid." Does invalid != NULL?

Comment: @dean `delete` simply frees the memory `x` pointed to. It doesn't have any effect on `x` itself, and it doesn't magically clear any other variables elsewhere in your program that point to the same memory.

Comment: @dean - I post that answer whenever I see code such as yours wonder why when they attempt to *adjust the value of a variable inside a function*, they don't understand why nothing changed.  It boils down to you attempting to change the value of something in a function, and attempting to see those changes reflect back to the caller.  There are only two ways of doing that -- pass by reference, or pass a pointer to whatever you're trying to change.  The thing you're trying to change is a Node*, so to change a Node*, you should pass a Node** or a Node*&.

Comment: @dvnrrs Okay. I think I have a grip of what has happened. The object area was deleted, `X` is still pointing to that area (assuming I don't set `X` to null). And the `next` pointer outside the function, which is what I really want to set to `NULL` is still pointing to the same mem location with a now-invalid object. Correct or wrong?

Comment: @dean -- all "delete" does is to tell you "the memory has been deallocated and it now belongs to the system to use in whatever ways it sees fit".  That can mean anything -- the runtime may fill it with zeros, or it may just sit there with no changes, or something else.  What you can't do is take that deallocated memory block and attempt to use it again, since that block is not yours anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The both functions are invalid.

In the first function you omitted statements that set correctly data member `next` of the current node.

That is the function has to look as

```
void deleteNode( Node *x ) 
{
    if ( x )
    {
        while ( x->next != NULL )
        {
            x->data = x->next->data;
            Node *tmp = x->next;
            x->next = x->next->next;
            x = tmp;
        }

        delete x;
    }
}
```

Nevertheless this function does not allow to remove the head of the list if it is the only element of the list.

The second function at least has undefined behaviour because `x->next` can be equal to NULL and as the result the condition in loop

```
while(x->next->next != NULL){
```

is invalid.

Comment: I was assuming the node has to be in the middle. I was aware of the corner case of the node being the last element in the array.

Comment: @dean It is a bad assumption.